# Poster for a display board of size 4' high and 8' across

Tags: posters

I have a poster presentation at a conference coming up. I know I can use other software to create a poster. However, I would like to use Latex since I have some mathematics involved. Is there a template that would work for me? My poster will go on a board of size 4' high and 8' across.

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Many people seem to use [`baposter`](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/).

Comment: Will it be okay for 4 by 8 board? Or do I need to adjust the size?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`baposter`](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/) class.

You can adjust the `fontscale` option until you are happy with the font sizes.

## MWE

(Don't you love the default colours?)

```
\documentclass[paperwidth=96in,paperheight=48in,landscape,fontscale=0.2]{baposter}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{
  headershape=rectangle,
  headerborder=closed,
  textborder=rectangle,
}{}{Poster Title}{Poster Author}

\headerbox{Highlighted box}{name=box1}{\lipsum[1-2]}

\headerbox{Highlighted box}{below=box1}{%
  \tiny tiny\par
  \scriptsize scriptsize\par
  \footnotesize footnotesize\par
  \small small\par
  \normalsize normalsize\par
  \large large\par
  \Large Large\par
  \LARGE LARGE\par
  \Huge Huge\par
}

\headerbox{Highlighted box}{column=1}{\lipsum[3-4]}

\headerbox{Highlighted box}{column=2}{\lipsum[4-5]}

\headerbox{Highlighted box}{column=3}{\lipsum[6-7]}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]